# Execute BCP from remote machine

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

I have one server with the sql database and manager studio and another server from where I want to execute the bcp command from. Could I use (possibly a `.bat` file) to generate a `.txt` file on the same server? Or does anyone have any other suggestions? It is for a person who does not have any knowledge of BD and wants to execute at any time, so I'm not using a job scheduled.

I tried the following, it does not work on the second server but it shows the expected result on the first.

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(255), @bcpc VARCHAR(8000)
SET @SQL = 'select * from BaseDatos.dbo.tabla'

SET @bcpc = 'bcp "' + @SQL + '" queryout'
SET @bcpc = @bcpc + ' c:\test\archivo.txt -c -t"|" -Usa -P'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpc

print @bcpc
```

Comment: As a side note, if you can, avoid using xp_cmdshell. It introduces a security risk. If access to xp_cmdshell is not restricted (it should be completely disabled) anyone who can execute will have their OS commands executed as the account used to run the SQL Server service. This is a good time to shift to an SSIS package to handle any needed OS commands within a database solution. Just an FYI.

Comment: @jamie thank you, I will take a look

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
EXECUTE (master.xp_cmdshell@bcpc) AT server2
```

If you are getting no result:

1) Is the Basedatos.dbo.tabla on server 2? If not, create a linked server so that you can reference server1.basedatos.dbo.tabla in order for BCP running on server 2 to get the data from Server 1

2) Check all permissions on server 2.

Comment: Is the Basedatos database on the second server? If not, you'll need to create a linked server back to server 1 and adjust your SQL to include the linked server.

Comment: no, the first server has the DB, the second is connected by network .. I will try this configuration, can I do it in the manager studio, right?

Comment: Yes you can do it in SSMS. You need to make sure your account has permissions on both servers and that RPC=Yes in the linked server definition.

Answer (score 0):

The bcp command you are building does not include the -S option to specify which SQL Server to get data from. I believe, if it's working on your "Server A" this is because BCP must default to the local default instance. However, when you try to run the BCP command on "Server B" you no longer have the same default SQL Server instance (if you have one at all). Try adding the -S option to specify the name of the "Server A" into the BCP command.

Imma double check on the "default" server value if -S is not used.

Yep...

> -S server_name [\instance_name] Specifies the instance of SQL Server to which to connect. If no server is specified, the bcp utility
>   connects to the default instance of SQL Server on the local computer.
>   **This option is required** when a bcp command is run from a remote
>   computer on the network or a local named instance. To connect to the
>   default instance of SQL Server on a server, specify only server_name.
>   To connect to a named instance of SQL Server, specify
>   server_name\instance_name.

Comment: I made the change but still does not create the file

Comment: Using the the command you are building on Server B and are executing within SQL Server using "xp_cmdshell", copy and paste that command into a DOS command window and execute the bcp statement directly to the operating system Let's eliminate SQL Server for now. Does the command run on it's own? Can you share the command that is being stored in @bcpc

Comment: What is the result of the execution when you run the bcp command directly in DOS?

Comment: you are right, there is an error! if execute in server 2 -> bcp "select * from BaseDatos.dbo.tabla" queryout c:\test\archivo.txt -c -T -t"|" -S DESKTOP-JCB5\WIND_ION 
SQLState = 28000, NativeError = 18452
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication.

Comment: You have a network hurdle to address. This is not purely a SQL Server topic anymore :(

Comment: How do you execute the DOS command on Server B? Did you open a session on the server? Remote desktop/or sit at computer and logon? I'm pretty sure your Server B and Server A are on different domains. Domain A does not trust Domain B. Probably a prod and test/development domain kinda thing. It says that the login is from an untrusted domain, but you were able to logon with same credentials and successfully queried Server A already right? Too much going on here now to answer a BCP quetion. My answer does address your original question. You DO need to include the -S option.

Comment: At least we know now that you are reaching (or trying to reach) Server A from Server B... just have permission issues. Good luck!

Comment: that's what it seems .. it's a network thing, I'll see how to solve this with the network manager, thanks!